# Socket io event handling ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, socket.io

I am using **socket** for chatting app. I am connecting socket on two `viewControllers` VC1 and VC2. When I am on VC1 all working fine, callback properly working. When i push to VC2 and come back to VC1, the Socket callback is coming on VC2. But at that time my **presentViewController** is VC1.

If any one have any idea about socket connect/disconnect on specific viewControllers, so please suggest.

**Thanks**

May be my socket lib is old so `[self.socket removeAllHandlers]; is not working with me`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove all handles before reconnecting socket and add handles again.

```
if (self.socket.status == SocketIOClientStatusDisconnected)
        [self.socket removeAllHandlers];

    [self.socket on:kConnect callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {

        NSLog(@"socket connected");
    }];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply
[self.socket removeAllHandlers]; is not found.. please see my updated question.

Comment: Which third party sdk are you using. This is for SocketIOClient of Socket.IO-Client-Swift sdk

Comment: i am using old obj c version.  
//  socket.io.js.h
//  SocketIO
//  Created by Patrick Perini on 6/13/14.